# Whos downvoting every question lately?

Tags: discussion, questions, down-votes, voting, serial-voting

Every new post I feel like, no matter how good or bad it is, gets an immediate downvote. Is this one person serially voting (if so could CMs take care of that) or is this just a bunch of people randomally doing this. Some notable example of good questions that have way too many downvotes:

1. [What are the different ways of handling runtime errors?](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/15/what-are-different-ways-of-handling-runtime-errors) Our highest voted question at a score of 33 has 2 downvotes.
2. [Why do some programming languages choose to have a dedicated keyword for `elseif` instead of using `else` + `if` like in C?](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/9/why-do-some-programming-languages-choose-to-have-a-dedicated-keyword-for-elseif) Our second highest voted question at a score of 28 has 1 downvote
3. [What different types of garbage collection are there, and what benefits do they provide?](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/24/what-different-types-of-garbage-collection-are-there-and-what-benefits-do-they) It has a score of 23 with 1 downvote
4. [How to transpile goto into a language that lacks it](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/1064/how-to-transpile-goto-to-a-language-that-lacks-it) It has a score of 21 with one downvote

Those are all taken from the top 5 scored questions on this site. 4 out of 5 have at least one downvote. No explanatory comment. And its not just the highest voted questions. A very large portion of our questions at large how unexplained downvotes on good posts. If this is one person can the CMs please find out who and deal with them appropriately and if this is multiple people can the CMs still please find out who and deal with them appropiately.

Comment: People have the right to downvote for whatever reason they wish

Comment: True enough but Im pretty sure this is serial voting at this point which is not allowed. You are not allowed to downvote every question you see for no reason (ive gotten suspeded for doign that) @mousetail

Comment: Several people have publicly stated they dislike most of our questions so they have a good reason to down-vote most of them

Comment: So I can go to Code Golf and downvote every question because I dont like code golfing? I think theres a flaw in that logic @mousetail

Comment: Some people have been downvoting every math question on code golf, because they don't like math. Same way people have been downvoting all questions they view as too unfocused or too opinion based here.

Comment: But its literally every single question with no rhyme or reason. @mousetail

Comment: It's not though, I have no reason to think the same people are down-voting every question. [This one for example](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/q/1876/8) has no downvotes. This person or people are only downvoting specific types of questions they dislike and leaving others alone. There could be multiple people who dislike different categories of questions

Comment: And its answers too @mousetail

Comment: That's just one example, you'll find many questions with no downvotes

Comment: Try to find me another site where 4 of the top 5 questions have a upvote to downvote ratio lower than 40 @mousetail

Comment: Most sites are like that. Stack Overflow is one example where many posts are actually down-votes. Most posts on most sites are +0/-0 which makes them trivially match your criterea

Comment: No for simplicity I said 4 of the top 5 questions @mousetail

Comment: Nearly every question tagged [tag:regex] on stack overflow has at least 4 downvotes

Comment: Theres only 2 questions there and yes one is heavily downvoted for no reason @mousetail

Comment: The regex tag on stack overflow, not the one here

Comment: I dont have the rep to see vote counts there...but this isnt just a tag its the whole site @mousetail

Comment: It is a tag though, it's [tag:pros-cons] and [tag:syntax], and several other tags people have very publicly stated why they don't like. That those happen to be our top questions is a coincidence.

Comment: No, it’s pretty random @mousetail

Comment: I hope its not just one person but if it is I wouldn't worry too much. The community will still upvote good questions from you as you have already seen. Your enemy if you truly have one will be lost in the noise.

Comment: Its everyones enemy and its still serial voting @BruceAdams

Comment: There are systems to detect it automtically see - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me

Comment: But under 5 downvotes per person per day isnt detected. Besides isnt not against me its again like every question period @BruceAdams

Comment: I think we should rejoice for this pattern. On Stack Overflow there is an incredibly strong tendency to upvote; only the most dedicated curators cast a significant fraction of downvotes. The result is mediocre old questions without outdated answers that get disproportionate attention and stand in the way of much better content. I've lost count of the times I discovered I had cast the first downvote on Stack Overflow on something that had dozens of upvotes (both questions and answers), while being able to point to a very clear and serious issue.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to answer this question, nor does there need to be. People can (and do) vote however they want. We certainly cannot divine their reasoning, but it doesn’t really matter. The questions are good questions, and their scores are positive, so the system is working fine. There is no injustice here, so there is no action to be taken. Relax.